# Jump from command window to simulink model block

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I create a link in Command Window for a block in a simulink model?

I found something like this:

```
    disp('<a href="matlab:magic(4)">Generate magic square</a>')
```

and that is possible to use href to jump to a line in a m-file. WHat is the syntacs to jump to a given block in a model? (I know in advance the block's gcb).

**Remark**
I am not fixed on href solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `hilite_system` can use something like following :

```
fprintf('<a href="matlab:hilite_system(''%s'')">Jump to Block</a>\n' , gcb )
```

Comment: in addition, do you know how i could jump directly from my m-script to a given block?

Comment: @Eagle Could you be specific ? M-Scripts are simple texts. For such navigation you need html document.

Comment: i have a M-Script that go over all blocks in my model and in case that it find a problem i would like to jump to this place.

Comment: @Eagle Well in that case simply use above in try..catch block on error display the message, you accordingly _might_ have to update gcb input. Specific problem ask in new post.